# Supported JDBC, JDK versions for Oracle 11g

Tags: jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

We are upgrading our DB from oracle 10g to 11g.

I hope our current JDK1.6 will support this.

What will be ideal JDBC versions for Oracle 11g ?

Currently we are using ojdbc.14.jar , will it support for 11g ?

Please confirm me

Comment: See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems like a question better directed to your appropriate Oracle support contact.

Comment: `ojdbc.14.jar` is for Java **1.4** You should use `ojdbc6.jar` with Java **6**.. All your questions are answered in the JDBC FAQ: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html

Answer (score 7):

According to [Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02), you should use OJDBC7.jar for java version 8

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Java inside the database? Or are you using Java to execute commands on the database?
If the former, see the product sheet for the Oracle version you're moving to. If the latter, anything older than the driver version that ships with the database should work, including the one you mention.

BUT, and that's a very big BUT, JDK 1.6 is out of support and has been for over a year. ojdbc14.jar is far older still and has been out of support for I think close to a decade.
You should really upgrade to JDK 1.8 (latest patch level is 45 or newer) and the ojdbc version that ships with the Oracle version you're upgrading to (ojdbc6).
Better performance, access to new APIs, security fixes, etc. etc.

Comment: For Java 8 you should use `ojdbc7.jar`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, you should use the correct one for your version of Oracle, as the driver may support operations not supported by the TNS Listener if you use a newer one.